# Check Box Pop-Up in Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Macro should display 2 option to the user select and depending upon that selection certain code must be executed

For example in bulletin

- Percentage1 = 5%
- Percentage2 = 2%

User will select either Option1 or Option2 depeding upon the input macro should run accordingly.

Above condition is small part of my entire macro

Below is the code that has to be in selection box

```
CallCount1 = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Selection.AutoFilter field:=16, Criteria1:="ABANDON"
AbCount1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
Percentage1 = (AbCount1 / CallCount1) * 100
MsgBox Percentage1
Selection.AutoFilter field:=14, Criteria1:=">=60"
AbCount2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").AutoFilter.Range.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells.Count - 1
AbCount = AbCount1 - AbCount2
CallCount2 = CallCount1 - AbCount2
Percentage2 = (AbCount2 / CallCount2) * 100
MsgBox Percentage2
```

Comment: It is not clear what your question is.

Comment: Create a UserForm

Comment: With how your question is worded right now, *I* would interpret it as a request for someone to write specific code for you. Let me be blunt -- that's highly unlikely to happen. If you're not sure how to get a selection from a user; I would recommended looking into either a userform (allows customization, and more complex inputs) or a `MsgBox` (minimal customization and limited selections; i.e. OK and Cancel, Yes and No, etc.). If that's not what you're wondering about, perhaps you could try editing your question?

Comment: You might be interested in this custom message boxes. [here](https://github.com/krishKM/Modern-UI-Components-for-VBA/blob/master/README.md#show-cool-dialogbox)

Comment: Hi All,
     I got the below code from my colleague and this is useful and exactly what I required.

'Fun = Application.InputBox("select 1 or 2" & vbLf & "1." & Percentage1 & "" & vbLf & "2." & Percentage2 & "", "Enter value", 1)
If Fun=1 Then Code1 else Code2 End If'